# jquery expand table not starting as hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make an expandable table, where many rows have a button you can press to toggle a child row for each row. This seems to be functioning but I want for it to begin with child row closed. How can I do this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.RowToClick').click(function() {
    $(this).nextAll('tr').each(function() {
      if ($(this).is('.RowToClick')) {
        return false;
      }
      $(this).toggle();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table border=0>
  <tr class="RowToClick">
    <td><button>+</button></td>
    <td>hello</td>
  </tr>

  <tr><td class="additionalRow">Data Row 1 Goes Here...</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="additionalRow">Data Row 1 Goes Here...</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="additionalRow">Data Row 1 Goes Here...</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="additionalRow">Data Row 1 Goes Here...</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="additionalRow">Data Row 1 Goes Here...</td></tr>
</table>

<table border=0>
  <tr class="RowToClick"><button>+</button></tr>
  <tr><td class="additionalRow">Data Row 1 Goes Here...</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="additionalRow">Data Row 1 Goes Here...</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="additionalRow">Data Row 1 Goes Here...</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="additionalRow">Data Row 1 Goes Here...</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="additionalRow">Data Row 1 Goes Here...</td></tr>
</table>

<table border=0>
  <tr class="RowToClick"><button>+</button></tr>
  <tr><td>Data Row 1 Goes Here...</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Data Row 2 Goes Here...</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Data Row 3 Goes Here...</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Data Row 4 Goes Here...</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Data Row 5 Goes Here...</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: could you add a jsfiddle pls ?

Comment: @Dwza you can put this code into jsfiddle. The only problem is that there is no _jQuery 1.5.1_ in jsfiddle, because this version is too  old. Maybe OP uses IE5 as well...

Comment: than use the snippet build in SOF, there is a 1.5.1 version...

Comment: Is this you need http://jsfiddle.net/evGd6/92/

Comment: What is the reasoning behind closing the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a row in your jquery

```
$('.RowToClick').nextAll('tr').toggle();
```

and put the Rowname in same TD like button

```
<td><button>+</button> Row 1</td>
```

so it looks like

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.RowToClick').nextAll('tr').toggle();
  $('.RowToClick').click(function() {
    $(this).nextAll('tr').each(function() {
      if ($(this).is('.RowToClick')) {
        return false;
      }
      $(this).toggle();
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table border=0>
  <tr class="RowToClick"><td><button>+</button> Row 1</td></tr>

  <tr><td class="additionalRow">Data Row 1 Goes Here...</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="additionalRow">Data Row 1 Goes Here...</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="additionalRow">Data Row 1 Goes Here...</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="additionalRow">Data Row 1 Goes Here...</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="additionalRow">Data Row 1 Goes Here...</td></tr>
</table>

<table border=0>
  <tr class="RowToClick"><td><button>+</button> Row 2</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="additionalRow">Data Row 1 Goes Here...</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="additionalRow">Data Row 1 Goes Here...</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="additionalRow">Data Row 1 Goes Here...</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="additionalRow">Data Row 1 Goes Here...</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="additionalRow">Data Row 1 Goes Here...</td></tr>
</table>

<table border=0>
  <tr class="RowToClick"><td><button>+</button> Row 3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Data Row 1 Goes Here...</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Data Row 2 Goes Here...</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Data Row 3 Goes Here...</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Data Row 4 Goes Here...</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Data Row 5 Goes Here...</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Maybe I confuse, I want to start data row "" goes here ... not displaying

Comment: it is not displayed on beginning and showed by pressing the + button... that's wrong ?

Comment: No, why does the word row 1 jump

Comment: so you want the word `row 1` hidden after expanding ?

Comment: The word  "Row 1" should no move

Comment: The word next to the button, I want to stay still when toggle

Comment: now it won't jump anymore

Comment: updated it again, actually you don't need the colespan because you content data is only one td. If your data builds more than one td you may have to add the colspan. But its not bad if its in there :)

Answer (score 0):

Add td inside tr

```
<tr class="RowToClick">
    <td>
        <button>+</button>
    </td>
    <td>hello</td>
</tr>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/evGd6/94/)**

**CSS**

```
.RowToClick ~ tr{
    display :none;
}
```

Comment: @ImBetterThanYou i updated now check demo